# Help to convert this PHP code to VB.NET code

Tags: php, xml, vb.net, post, encode

I have a code to send XML via POST. But this code is in PHP and I need it in VB.NET.

Any help to convert this code?

```
$XMLFile= (here i have created the xml file. XML is encoded ISO-8859)

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"URL WHERE I SEND XML");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"XMLDATA=".$XMLFile);
$results=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$results=stripslashes($results);

$xmlreturned=new SimpleXMLElement($results);

if($xmlreturned->NotificationResultHeader->RRC==0){
if($xmlreturned->NotificationResultList->NotificationResult->NRC==0){
echo "OK. SUCCES";
```

And how I convert this PHP code too:

```
$msg=htmlentities($msg);
$msg=urlencode($msg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc.aspx) and [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) classes. The code could would look something like this (*my VB is a bit rusty these days*):

```
Dim xmlDoc as XmlDocumnet
'
'  prepare you xml doc here...
'
Dim encoding as ASCIIEncoding = New ASCIIEncoding()
Dim postData as String 
postData = "XMLDATA=" + xmlDoc.ToString()
Dim data() as Byte 
data = encoding.GetBytes(postData)

' Prepare web request...
Dim myRequest as HttpWebRequest 
    myRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("URL TO POST HERE"), HttpWebRequest)
myRequest.Method = "POST"
myRequest.ContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length
Dim newStream as Stream  = myRequest.GetRequestStream()
' Send the data.
newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)

' Get the response
Dim myResponse as HttpWebResponse
myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse()
```

Answer (score 0):

See: [htmlentities solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode.aspx) and [urlencode solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx)

And as far as curl, it looks like you're trying to call a web service.  If it's a proper web service (meaning there is a WSDL and an XSD somewhere), you should add a Service Reference (or a Web Reference if you're in VS2005 or VS2003) to your project, which will generate a proxy for you to use (instead of manually dumping XML to a server).